# Weird percentage computing with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, carousel

I have a carousel on my page that is acting a little funny. Though my jsfiddle works without a hitch, it operates very differently on my site.

Here's the site that's working funky: http://drainteractive.com/conceptstudio/

Here's the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ExRR7/13/

The code in my functions.js file is exactly the same as what is in the jsfiddle:

```
$('.move-left').click(function(){
$('.belt').animate({right: '-=50%'}, 0);
});

$('.move-right').click(function(){
$('.belt').animate({right: '+=50%'}, 0);
});
```

However, on the site, the second time I click on one of the arrows, things get bizarre. After the initial 50% jump, the `belt.div` moves somewhere around 600% to the right. Then about 3000%.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

EDIT: okay, the jsfiddle has +/-=25% instead of 50%, but that's not what's causing the problem.

Comment: It looks like `$('.belt').css('right')` is returning pixels.. So the first time it works, because the css `right` property is 0. After animating once, the css `right` property is 477.5px. jQuery gets the current css right property (which is returned as 477.5px), adds 50 (the percent you want to add), then sets the css right property to the resulting 527.5 and adds `%` to the end. It continues on from there.

Comment: This explains why the percentage varied depending on the size of my browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test but this should work

```
   var count = 0;

   $('.move-left').click(function(){
      count -= 50;
      $('.belt').animate({right: count + '%'}, 0);
   });

   $('.move-right').click(function(){
      count += 50;
      $('.belt').animate({right: count + '%'}, 0);
   });
```

Yes just like Jason P said. when you animate the `.belt` the first time the value of `right` would be auto. so jQuery add's `50%` jQuery uses `getComputedStyle` (if I'm right)
to get the value of right so although the style attribute will be `50% getComputedStyle` will return the value in `px`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.move-left').click(function() {
    var width = $('.belt li').width() + 44 + 'px'; // li width + padding
    $('.belt').animate({right: '-=' + width}, 0);
});

$('.move-right').click(function() {
    var width = $('.belt li').width() + 44 + 'px'; // li width + padding
    $('.belt').animate({right: '+=' + width}, 0);
});
```

Comment: I get what you're going for, but this doesn't work with responsive layouts out of the box.